# JSON serializing Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using the python package pymongo to retrieve data from a mongodb database.

```
>>> r = collection.find()   # returns an object of class 'Cursor'
```

Then I convert to a list

```
>>> l = list(r)             # returns a 'list' of 'dict'
```

here is what print(l) returns:

```
>>> [{u'date': datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 10, 10, 45), u'_id': 1, u'name': u'name1', u'value': 11},{u'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 10, 10, 45), u'_id': 2, u'name': u'name2', u'value': 22}]
```

Now I need to convert to JSON so that I can manipulate it.

```
>>> json.dumps(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 178, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 12, 11, 14) is not JSON serializable
```

I have also tried to follow *http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/json_util.html* without success:
Edit: the recent version of the link is http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html

```
>>> json.dumps(l, default=json_util.default)  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
NameError: name 'json_util' is not defined
```

**Note:** precisely I need to push this result to R using the R package rPython and its function rPython::python.get("l")

**Side Question**: What is the u (u'Date', u'name', etc..) before each field in the list of dict?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The pymongo documentation you pointed is obsolete. If you're using version 1.7 I recommend updating. With a more recent version you can do this:

```
from bson.json_util import dumps

dumps(l)
```

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/json_util.html

**Side answer**: `u'name'`, `u'date'`, `u'_id'` etc are the names of the fields of the document on the database.

Comment: Thanks!
regarding the Side question, what does the u' mean? I thought 'name','date','_id' were the field names

Comment: @rock `u'literal'` is an Unicode string in Python 2. They are much like strings, but are specified in the syntax using a preceding `u`. Pymongo is decoding the field names to Unicode, that is why you are seeing them in that form. If you field names contain only ASCII characters, you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: ok thanks, will read about that. I might have to play with this format as my fields also have dates

Comment: Thank you I use this code on bottle framework:

@route('/admin/users', method=['OPTIONS', 'GET'])
def get_users():
    entity = db['users'].find()

    l = list(entity)

    return dumps(l)

Comment: dumps method taking lot of time for 100 documents

Answer (score 13):

```
from bson import json_util



json.dumps(result,default=json_util.default)
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference with Rafa's solution?

Comment: Your second line returns me :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'json_util' is not defined

Comment: Do you have pymongo installed ?

Comment: yes. I think the problem is that I have a more recent version of pymongo. Now I should follow http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html

Comment: Which version of pymongo are you using, as the import module is different in different versions. You could also try `from pymongo import json_util` for older versions.

Comment: I am using 2.6.3 (current)

Answer (score 4):

In my situation, this error is due to mongo DB id object in flask
all you have to do is convert id (NOTE: if you need id convert it else you can pop it too)
I'm sharing my solution which I figured out hope this helps someone

```py
from flask import jsonify

def get_data(self,data):
     data['_id'] = str(data['_id'])
     return data

app =  Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def apimethod():
     temp = [self.get_data(i) for i in self.collection.find()]
     return jsonify(temp)
```

also dumps from pymongo don't help alot

```py
from bson.json_util import dumps,loads
```

because it is returning a string instead of dict which was expected in my situation to create API and I have to load again if I did dumps.

Comment: This is the correct answer if someone wants to have a JSON returned from the API instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I wrote a code that converts document to dictionary. You can use that for reference. Pass the object obtained by find_one() into documentToJson() method and the results of find() into convertDocumentsToJson. There is type in the name Json, instead the code converts to Dict rather than json.

```
from bson.json_util import dumps

class UtilService:

def __init__(self):
    pass

@staticmethod
def pinCodeParser(path):
    location = {}
    f = open(path)
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        location[words[1]] = (words[-3],words[-2])
    return location

@staticmethod
def listHelper(str):
    s = []
    str = str.split(',')
    for e in str:
        s.append(e.replace("[","").replace("]",""))
    return s

@staticmethod
def parseList(str):
    if ',' in str:
        return UtilService.listHelper(str)
    return str

@staticmethod
def trimStr(str):
    return str.replace('"','')

@staticmethod
def documentToJson(document):
    document = eval(dumps(document))
    mp = {}
    for key, value in document.iteritems():
        if "_id" in key:
            mp["id"] = str(value["$oid"])
        else:
            mp[ UtilService.trimStr(key) ] = UtilService.parseList( value )
    return mp

@staticmethod
def convertDocumentsToJson(documents):
    result = []
    for document in documents:
        result.append(UtilService.documentToJson(document))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me - thank you.

Wanted to share my final solution to get the JSON back into a JSON/Dictionary Object: (Based on your example)

```
from bson.json_util import dumps, loads
r = collection.find()
l = list(r) # Converts object to list
d = dumps(l) # Converts to String
dict_needed = loads(d[0]) # Serializes String and creates dictionary
```

Now you have the JSON in a dictionary object and can edit as needed.