# How to correctly jsonify Mongo DB documents when "ObjectId is not JSON serializable?"

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, flask

I'm setting up MongoDB for my Python app, and have this code:

```
@app.route('/user/<firstName>', methods=['GET'])
def getUser(firstName):
    print(firstName)
    return jsonify({'users': Users.find({'first_name': firstName})[0]})
```

which throws this error: TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable
due to the `_id` field being '_id': ObjectId('5e8676dc0d16f3567167d889').

How do I get around this?

Comment: did you see [JSON serializing Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674311/json-serializing-mongodb)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON serializing Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674311/json-serializing-mongodb)

Comment: @Joe No, they do not.

Comment: If the json_util functions that convert BSON to JSON don't help, what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @Joe Trying to jsonify Pymongo objects, but I was able to using a custom JSON encoder. It's due to the ObjectId field not being serializable.

Comment: ObjectId is BSON type, so the json_util functions from the BSON library can serialize it.

Comment: @Joe That would mean I need to serialize the rest with another JSON library right?

Comment: not really, if you're using a mongodb object, you've already got the BSON library loaded, or python wouldn't know what an ObjectId is.  As in, rather than writing a custom function to serialize a BSON type, use the type conversion provided by the BSON library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this code somewhere, and it's working now.
*Please tag if anyone knows where this came from.

```
class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    ''' extend json-encoder class'''
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
            return str(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)


# use the modified encoder class to handle ObjectId & datetime object while jsonifying the response.
app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
```